# Mock a variable value in JS unit-tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

How could I mock(stub?) variable from external module in unit-tests?

I have a lib which would be running at **browser** as well as at **node.js**:

```
exports.Utils = (function (Config) {
    return {
        sum: function (val) {
            return Config.defaultVal + val;
        }
    };

}(exports.Config));
```

Because tests run with only one (`Utils.js`) file, `Config` would be `undefined` here.

Tests runs in node.js enviroment.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var Utils = require('./src/Utils.js').Utils;

describe("Test for Utils sum", function () {
    it("example sum test", function () {
        //How could I specify Config.defaultVal here?
        expect(Utils.sum(1)).to.be.equal(2);
    });
});
```

Perhaps I should use `sinonjs`, but I didn't find clear example for my case.

Comment: Did you try `var Config = require('path/to/config')` in your test file ? it should load the config in exports.

Comment: It's still undefined

Comment: How does the `Utils.js` get ahold of the `Config` ? It seems like it should loading `Config` somehow. Please share that code as well.